# PHP session lost after redirection in php 7.3

Tags: php, bluehost, php-7.3

i am using bluehost server to host my PHP website. When i redirect page from one to another session values will be lost.
my code is given below.

```
$_SESSION['access'] = "admin";
header('Location:../test.php');
exit();
```

The `$_SESSION['access']` value is not getting in test page. but the value is getting when i code change like this

```
$_SESSION['access'] = "admin";
header('Location:test.php');
exit();
```

Comment: Do you start the session in all your scripts interacting with a session?

Comment: Isn't your question actually about the redirect that is not working in case one?

Comment: @Qirel yes...my test page code is   <?php
session_start();
echo "testing";
echo $_SESSION['access'];

Comment: @B001ᛦ no, redirection is working , but in the first case i didnt get the session value in the redirected page. but its working in the second case

Comment: Open *Chrome Developer Tools > Network tab*, check *Preserve log*. Look at response headers, specifically *Set-Cookie* of the initial request in both scenarios. Is there any difference?